# https://rubygems.org/ is not a URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

While trying to add any URL to gem sources, I find that this URL is not a URI. For example
when I execute

```
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org
```

It tells me that

> https://rubygems.org is not a URI

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what is your ruby version ? Have you tried with http instead of https?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3, sorry I don't understand !

Comment: @AmitSiddhu Yes I've and the same output !!

Comment: ok thanks, if you are using a rails app than what is the output of `bundle update` command

Comment: I've reinstalled the Ruby so now I have this new error: Error fetching https://rubygems.org:
        SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read serv
rtificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Ok, here is the fix of this ssl issue on windows: https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74481/discussion-between-mina-f-beshay-and-amit-siddhu).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the uri component of Ruby itself.
I think following will work:
Go to `/lib/ruby/1.9.3/uri`, open `common.rb`, find userinfo and replace the definition with this line

```
ret[:USERINFO] = userinfo = "(?:[#{unreserved};:&=+$,\\\\]|#{escaped})*"
```

Comment: No change ! The same output !

Answer (score 0):

might be the DNS problem, although i am not sure but give it a try with open DNS like 8.8.8.8

Comment: I actually use the DNS of Google